# What is my user ID?

Tags: support

I signed up with SP.SE site with my gmail account. Now my Question is, what is my User ID?

I wana use that in  script to check the badge progress but whatever i type never accepted.

I tried my gmail email address and also short id but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watching the user profile, you have your ID in the URL:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/21563/waqas-sarwar-mcse

In your case it's 21563 which also will show if you hit a share link.

Good luck with the scripting

Comment: thanks, that's works